# Is this a satisfactory answer to a Dietel C# exercise on classes and objects

Tags: c#, class

Basically, I'm trying to teach myself C#.  And tbh, I really don't get the way C# does classes.  The way the book teaches you, they say use a field, constructor and properties.  Why on earth have 3 ways in your code to write the same thing?! I'm treating the field as "field_length", the method variable as "Length" and the constructor as "length" (lower case).
How is this simplifying anything?  You have these get/set accessors which really add to the confusion. The book says: do it this way.  But could someone provide a few reasons for all this "administrative code" that doesn't do anything purposeful, but basically is there to support one or two lines of useful code.  (In this case it's just a practice class to make two simple rectangle calculations.  The two lines of useful code are just area = length* width and perimeter = 2*length + 2*width, the rest of it takes up the entire page!

So, here's the question from Dietel chapter 10 on Classes page 402.  Did I do it right?  And someone please explain why so much administrative overhead just for a simple problem.  3 ways to write length?  "Length" "length" and "field_length".  OMG, but this is the way they apparently want you to do things.

> Rectangle Class: Create a class **Rectangle**.  The class has attributes **length** and **width**, each of which default to 1.  It has read-only properties that calculate the **Perimeter** and the **Area** of the rectangle.  It has properties for both **length** and **width**.  The set accessors should verify that **length** and **width** are each floating point numbers greater than 0.0 and less than 20.0.  Write an app to test class **Rectangle**.

```
using System;

class Rectangle
{
private double field_length = 1;
private double field_width = 1;

public Rectangle(double Length, double Width)
{
    length = Length;
    width = Width;
}

public double length
{
    get { return field_length; }
    set { if((length>=0)&&(length<=20))
        field_length = value; }
}

public double width
{
    get { return field_width; }
    set { if((width>=0)&&(width<=20))
        field_width = value; }
}

public double Perimeter
{
    get { return 2 * field_width + 2 * field_length; ;}
    set { Perimeter = 2 * field_width + 2 * field_length; }
}

public double Area
{
    get { return field_length * field_width; }
    set { Area = field_width * field_length; }
}
}


using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(5, 6);
        Console.WriteLine(rect1.length);
        Console.WriteLine(rect1.width);
        Console.WriteLine(rect1.Perimeter);
        Console.WriteLine(rect1.Area);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this book is of the horror genre.

Comment: The setters on Perimeter and Area don't make sense. You can't set the value of a computed property like that. They should be get only

Comment: From the requirements: "It has **read-only** properties that calculate the Perimeter and the Area" (emphasis mine).  Your requirements also say nothing about having a constructor.  That, along with fixing the naming conventions you use, would turn this into a fairly reasonable program.

Comment: On a side note, your requirements uses the word "attributes" when it really means "fields" (you've used the *correct* term).  Attributes are something completely different; clearly it isn't intending to refer to them.

Comment: Isn't the point of the model, in this case `Rectangle`, to provide a skeleton of the object and not the data validation? One would think the controller - `Main()` - would check the validity of the rectangle's dimensions. The way it is written, the validation for setter `width` only swallows the permissible range of `n>0 && n<21`. This just seems like an awful mess.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: The point of a model is *exactly the opposite* of what you suggest.  The logic for the object should be encapsulated within it.  It should never assume that consuming code is going to manage the logic for it.  Consider a quote from Eric Raymond: `"Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around."`  I agree that the OP's implementation is flawed, but ignoring object oriented design won't fix it.

Comment: @David You learn something new every day. Thanks! :)

Comment: Anyone else find it funny that someone *learning* C#, and by the look of things, *Object Oriented Programming*, should be so self assured as to qualify basic building blocks of *OOP* as "not doing anything purposeful" and having no other use than "adding to the confussion".

Comment: @InBetween No, not at all.  I mean C# 6.0 is filled with features specifically designed to make code just like this shorter, simpler, and with a lot less boilerplate, specifically because code like this has so much boilerplate.  It's not inherent to what the code is doing, it's just the language being clunky.  He's simply not so used to the status quote as to not expect something better.

Comment: @Servy: Haven't read anything about new features in C# 6.0 so I am curious as to how it simplifies the code of this excercise. Have we really improved in boilerplate code when setter validations are needed? Another issue is if I would *design* the class some other way to leverage the added features, but that is another issue.

Comment: @InBetween In short, yes.  Expression-bodied members in particular would help.

Comment: @Sevy: Interesnting, I'll have a look into it. Anyhow your initial comment completely missed my point. The OP is stating that *constructors*, *fields* and *properties* are all different ways of doing the same thing which seems to imply that his grasp of *OOP* is, to say the least, tenuous which makes the generally disqualifying tone of his question somewhat bizarre. Anyhow, not worth discussing :p

Answer (score 6):

Let's take it a step at a time...

> Create a class Rectangle.

Easy:

```
public class Rectangle { }
```

> The class has attributes length and width

I assume from the context that these are public:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}
```

However, as a more advanced conceptual exercise I recommend that you also look into private setters and making the object *immutable*.  A "shape" like this sounds like it could very well be represented as a value type, so a struct or some immutable object sounds more applicable.  But I digress...

> each of which default to 1.

Sure, that's a job for a constructor:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public Rectangle()
    {
        Length = 1.0;
        Width = 1.0;
    }
}
```

> It has read-only properties that calculate the Perimeter and the Area of the rectangle.

The key here is "read-only".  So these properties have only getters and calculate on the fly:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public double Perimeter
    {
        get { return (2.0 * Length) + (2.0 * Width); }
    }

    public double Area
    {
        get { return Length * Width; }
    }

    public Rectangle()
    {
        Length = 1.0;
        Width = 1.0;
    }
}
```

> It has properties for both length and width.

Sweet, I guessed correctly earlier!  Otherwise I'd have to refactor a little bit.  But it looks like this is already satisfied.

> The set accessors should verify that length and width are each floating point numbers greater than 0.0 and less than 20.0.

*Now* comes some refactoring.  The auto-implemented properties won't suffice anymore and need to become manual properties.  Let's start with that:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private double length;
    public double Length
    {
        get { return length; }
        set { length = value; }
    }

    private double width;
    public double Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set { width = value; }
    }

    public double Perimeter
    {
        get { return (2.0 * Length) + (2.0 * Width); }
    }

    public double Area
    {
        get { return Length * Width; }
    }

    public Rectangle()
    {
        Length = 1.0;
        Width = 1.0;
    }
}
```

There, now we can add the validation:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private double length;
    public double Length
    {
        get { return length; }
        set
        {
            if ((value <= 0.0) || (value >= 20.0))
                throw new ArgumentException("Length must be greater than 0.0 and less than 20.0");
            length = value;
        }
    }

    private double width;
    public double Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set
        {
            if ((value <= 0.0) || (value >= 20.0))
                throw new ArgumentException("Width must be greater than 0.0 and less than 20.0");
            width = value;
        }
    }

    public double Perimeter
    {
        get { return (2.0 * Length) + (2.0 * Width); }
    }

    public double Area
    {
        get { return Length * Width; }
    }

    public Rectangle()
    {
        Length = 1.0;
        Width = 1.0;
    }
}
```

I think that covers it.  As a matter of personal preference you might drop the constructor and set the default values in-line now that we're using private members instead of auto-implemented properties.  Personally I prefer keeping that stuff in the constructor just so it's all in one place.  (Also, as the object grows in complexity, putting too much logic in in-line construction leads to *very* difficult to debug exceptions.)

> Write an app to test class Rectangle.

An ***app***?  *sigh*  Your instructor should be ashamed.  This is a job for ***unit tests***!  The tests for this one are pretty easy, [and should actually have been written *first*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

What are we going to test?  Let's start with the defaults:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RectangleHasDefaults()
{
    // arrange
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();

    // act
    //  no action to perform

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1.0, rectangle.Length);
    Assert.AreEqual(1.0, rectangle.Width);
}
```

That was easy, and it introduced us to the standard arrange/act/assert pattern which should be common to automated tests.  Let's move on to the  calculated properties:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RectangleHasPerimeter()
{
    // arrange
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();

    // act
    rectangle.Length = 2.0;
    rectangle.Width = 3.0;

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(10.0, rectangle.Perimeter);
}

[TestMethod]
public void RectangleHasArea()
{
    // arrange
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();

    // act
    rectangle.Length = 2.0;
    rectangle.Width = 3.0;

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(6.0, rectangle.Area);
}
```

Looks like the only thing left to test are the exception cases.  There are various ways to test exceptions, depending on the testing framework.  (And they have varying, sometimes infuriating effects on code coverage metrics.)  Since I'm assuming MSTest here, let's stick with that:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void LengthHasMinimum()
{
    // arrange
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();

    // act
    rectangle.Length = 0.0;

    // assert
    //  nothing to assert
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void LengthHasMaximum()
{
    // arrange
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();

    // act
    rectangle.Length = 20.0;

    // assert
    //  nothing to assert
}
```

For brevity I'll leave out the identical tests for `Width`, you can add those :)

Once all of this is in place, you might refactor to reduce some duplication.  That's up to you.  There's often a balance between code that's physically different vs. code that's semantically different.  A lot of these tests are *very* similar for example, though they test distinctly different things.  I would suggest keeping the semantics separated until there's very good reason to pursue de-duplication efforts.  After all, duplicated code is often better than the wrong abstraction.